# Msql Trigger timeout query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a trigger to execute a query after a timeout when data is inserted in certain table ? 
Is there any way to timeout trigger?

Answer (score -2):

Timing functions are best done through client-side scripting languages such as JavaScript (PHP is server-side).

However, client-side languages cannot execute SQL commands, so what I would recommend is using the AJAX (asynchronous javascript and XML), which allows you to use a javascript function to trigger a PHP function.

For example, the following would work:

```
<script src="wherever you placed your Jquery source file">

setTimeout(function(){

 $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "PHP processing gets done on this page",
data: {query: Search_Data}, //Search_Data is any data you wish to send to the next     page.
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#result").html(html).show();
}
});

}, 10000); //This would set make the AJAX function run in 100 seconds.
</script>

<div id="result"></div> // results appear here
```

Your PHP file would be of the following type:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['query'])){

//PHP code for SQL statement goes here.

}

?>
```

Comment: yup i am currently using it on my Server Side ! but i need something like, suppose  a request expires in 10 mins so after the insert query is executed for a request mysql should automatically trigger update query after 10 mins for  expired flag ! i don't want to rely on serverside or client side timeouts !